# Shortcut for and/or evaluation

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

Is there a shortcut for the following evaluation? One where I do not need to specify value a twice?

```
(a && b || a && c)
```

Thank you. :)

Comment: `(a && (b || c))`?

Comment: asp.net related how?

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't thinking clearly... nothing to do with asp net. What Camilo wrote is all I was looking for.

Comment: Probably that and also for missing the (fairly) obvious... I'm not even sure this is a C# specific question, or even a programming question, it's just basic boolean logic. Although I didn't downvote myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
(a && (b || c))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the condition with braces isn't clear enough for you:

```
switch (a)
{
    case true when b || c:
        Console.WriteLine($"{a} | {b} | {c}");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Nope!");
        break;
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8RCcCr

Comment: OP wants a **short**cut and you post that?

Comment: `One where I do not need to specify value a twice` -> `a` is only specified once :D

Comment: Let's not forget about the scalability, [what if our product manager wants to compare even more values?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/onnenI)